# creat floating action button to take picture

Tags: android

I want to create floating action button called (btn_fab) to take picture from camera I could make floating action button that take image from gallery  called  ( mFabPickImage) and send this image to segmentBitmap() function to make segmentation to it 
the problem is : my (btn_fab) take the picture but doesn't display it to fragment or create segmentation 
this is my code that initialize the 2 floating action buttons

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buckyButton = findViewById(R.id.buckysButton);


       //  src_img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.src_img) ;

       Intent intent=getIntent();

        String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");


        if(message=="hello"){

            initModel();


        }

      else if(message=="hi"){

            initModel2();

        }


        setCapture();
        setupViews();
    }

private boolean hasCamera(){
    return getPackageManager() .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
}
public void launchCamera(View view){
   Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

}

setupViews() to take image from gallery and setCapture() to take image from camera

```
 private void setupViews() {

    mFabPickImage = findViewById(R.id.fab_pick_image);
    if (mFabPickImage != null) {
        mFabPickImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                }

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                intent.setType("image/*");

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                ActivityLauncher.launchActivityForResult(MainActivity.this,
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)),
                        REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);


            }

        });
    }


 private void setCapture(){
    btn_fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    btn_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            String root =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()+"propic.jpg";
            uri=Uri.parse(root);
            startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        }
    });


}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Logger.debug("requestCode = 0x%02x, permission = [%s], grant = [%s]",
            requestCode,
            ArrayUtils.stringArrayToString(permissions, ","),
            ArrayUtils.intArrayToString(grantResults));
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_REQUIRED_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Logger.debug("permission granted, initialize model.");
            initModel();
            initModel2();

            if (mFabPickImage != null) {
                mFabPickImage.setEnabled(true);
                mFabPickImage.setBackgroundTintList(
                        ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.colorAccent)));
            }
             if(btn_fab!=null){
                 btn_fab.setEnabled(true);
                 btn_fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.colorAccent)) );
            }
        } else {
            Logger.debug("permission denied, disable fab.");
        }


        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

and this is my onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Logger.debug("requestCode = %d, resultCode = %d, data = %s",
                requestCode,
                resultCode,
                data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Uri ImageCaptureUri=data.getData();
        Logger.debug("capture: %s", ImageCaptureUri);
        // Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
        // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        // src_img.setImageBitmap(photo);
        if (ImageCaptureUri != null) {
           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
                getContentResolver()
                        .takePersistableUriPermission(ImageCaptureUri, takeFlags);
            }

            segmentImage2(ImageCaptureUri);
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    Logger.debug("requestCode = %d, resultCode = %d, data = %s",
            requestCode,
            resultCode,
            data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri pickedImageUri = data.getData();
            Logger.debug("picked: %s", pickedImageUri);

            if (pickedImageUri != null) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
                    getContentResolver()
                            .takePersistableUriPermission(pickedImageUri, takeFlags);
                }

                segmentImage(pickedImageUri);
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
```

and this is the function that take the image and make segmentation

```
private void segmentImage(Uri pickedImageUri){
    Fragment fragment = findFragment(R.id.fragment_segment_bitmaps);

    if (fragment instanceof SegmentBitmapsFragment) {
        ((SegmentBitmapsFragment)fragment).segmentBitmap(pickedImageUri);//important note

    }

}

private void segmentImage2(Uri ImageCaptureUri){
    Fragment fragment = findFragment(R.id.fragment_segment_bitmaps);

    if (fragment instanceof SegmentBitmapsFragment) {
        ((SegmentBitmapsFragment)fragment).segmentBitmap2(ImageCaptureUri);//important note

    }

}

 private void setPickImageEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (mFabPickImage != null) {
        mFabPickImage.setEnabled(enabled);

        int resId = enabled ? R.color.colorAccent : R.color.light_gray;
        mFabPickImage.setBackgroundTintList(
                ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(resId)));
    }
}
private void setPickImageEnabled2(boolean enabled) {
    if (btn_fab != null) {
        btn_fab.setEnabled(enabled);

        int resId = enabled ? R.color.colorAccent : R.color.light_gray;
        btn_fab.setBackgroundTintList(
                ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(resId)));
    }
}
```

and **this is SegmentBitmapFragment.java**

```
 public Loader<List<SegmentBitmap>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new SegmentBitmapsLoader(getContext(), mImageUri);

}


public void segmentBitmap(Uri pickedImageUri) {

    mImageUri = pickedImageUri;

    fastDisplayOrigin();

    restartLoader();
}
public void segmentBitmap2(Uri imageCaptureUri) {
    mImageUri = imageCaptureUri;

    fastDisplayOrigin();

    restartLoader();
}


private void fastDisplayOrigin() {
    if (mRecyclerView != null) {
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof AbsArrayRecyclerAdapter) {
            AbsArrayRecyclerAdapter bitmapsAdapter =
                    (AbsArrayRecyclerAdapter)adapter;

            bitmapsAdapter.clear();
            bitmapsAdapter.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_original, mImageUri));
            bitmapsAdapter.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_mask, (Bitmap)null));
            bitmapsAdapter.add(new SegmentBitmap(R.string.label_cropped, (Bitmap)null));


        }
    }
}
```